# React TextInput placeholder stuck at a specific value

Tags: reactjs, placeholder, textinput

I was working on a Social Media clone using React JS. But I wasn't able to change the placeholder value.
This is the code in my file `search.js` for rendering the search box as shown below

```
<div className="search_box">
 <TextInput
  placeholder="Search Chocolate"
  autoFocus
  value={value}
  valueChange={this.search}
  className="search"
 />
 <span className="search_icon">
  <FAIcon icon="search" />
 </span>
</div>
```

This is the code for the search box :
[image]

As you can see, even though the placeholder says **Chocolate**, it renders as **Instagram**
Also, to be sure, I used the react dev tools in chrome to check which renders this component and it also says that `search.js` the one that renders the search component

[image]

So, the placeholder in the dev tools even says that the placeholder is **Search Instagram** even though it is clearly **Search Chocolate** which is written in the `search.js`.

My full code for `search.js` is as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { post } from 'axios'
import MapSearch from './map-search/map-search'
import FAIcon from '../icons/font-awesome-icon'
import TextInput from '../input/text'

export default class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
    search: {
      users: [],
      groups: [],
      hashtags: [],
    },
  }

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({
      search: {
        users: [],
        groups: [],
        hashtags: [],
      },
    })
  }

  search = async ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ value })
    if (value.trim() != '') {
      let { data } = await post('/api/search-instagram', { value })
      this.setState({ search: data })
    } else {
      this.hide()
    }
  }

  clicked = () => {
    this.setState({ value: '' })
    this.hide()
  }

  render() {
    let {
      value,
      search: { users, groups, hashtags },
    } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="search_box">
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Search Chocolate"
            autoFocus
            value={value}
            valueChange={this.search}
            className="search"
          />
          <span className="search_icon">
            <FAIcon icon="search" />
          </span>
        </div>

        {users.length > 0 || groups.length > 0 || hashtags.length > 0 ? (
          <MapSearch
            users={users}
            groups={groups}
            hashtags={hashtags}
            clicked={this.clicked}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to change the placeholder value? I really don't know why it is stuck at that specific value despite the placeholder value being different.

## EDIT: Added code for `text.js` for `TextInput` component

```
import React from 'react'
import { string, func, oneOf, bool } from 'prop-types'

const TextInput = ({ type, placeholder, value, valueChange, ...props }) => (
  <input
    type={type}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    spellCheck="false"
    autoComplete="false"
    value={value}
    onChange={valueChange}
    {...props}
  />
)

TextInput.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  placeholder: '',
  value: '',
  maxLength: '255',
  disabled: false,
}

TextInput.propTypes = {
  type: oneOf(['text', 'email', 'password']),
  placeholder: string.isRequired,
  value: string.isRequired,
  valueChange: func.isRequired,
  maxLength: string,
  disabled: bool,
}

export default TextInput
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of `TextInput` component?

Comment: Sure @EmanueleScarabattoli I have added it now

Comment: if you do a global search for `Search Instagram` in your code (Ctrl +Shift + F in vscode), is this text present anywhere in your code?  Also try restarting your local dev server to make sure that local changes are reflected on UI

Comment: Also check the CSS class `search`, since, with some tricks, a placeholder can be set with CSS too.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot  @KaranGarg It was in bundle.js and in some snapshot files. Thanks a lot. I really wanted to do some functionality like global search but I wasn't sure how to do that. Now, I learnt it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks a lot too @EmanueleScarabattoli I got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Send the target value. Something like:
`valueChange={(e)=> this.search(e.target.value)}`

Comment: Sorry, how do you think this answer can be helpful?

Comment: OP says his input value isn't updated. I see no event passed to his onChange function. This is simply what I would do, and it work in 100% of my projects.

Comment: Maybe the question was not clear at the beginning, by the way "I wasn't able to change the placeholder value", so it is not a problem related the the value itself, but to placeholder instead :)

Comment: Aa yes, you're right, it was about the placeholder. Sorry I read the question a bit too fast.